# Sitecore Responsive Device Resolver not handling iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, sitecore

I'm on Sitecore 6.6.0 - 140410 - working on a mobile implementation for our Intranet.

- The Responsive Device Resolver package is installed & enabled.
- I have a Default layout named MainLayoutBase & have created a scaled down Mobile layout named MainLayoutMobile.
- The RDR sublayout has been added to the top of the body of both Layouts.
- I have a single RDR rule of "where the client's screen width is less than or equal to 500 pixels - set the context device to Mobile".

I save & publish my content - then select Preview.  Then Preview using the simulator 'None' shows everything I would expect from the Desktop version.  And when I select the 'Android Phone' simulator I get exactly what I want for my mobile version (basic as it is now).

However - when I select the iPhone (or Windows Phone) simulator, it shows me the Desktop version again - but on the small device  (not resizing at all either, which I can work around).

I need to know if I'm missing something simple or if there are specific additional rules/tricks for handling other devices?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is very simple:
I have a single RDR rule of "where the client's screen width is less than or equal to 500 pixels - set the context device to Mobile".

The iPhone screen resolution is higher then 500px. See http://www.iphoneresolution.com/